# What is difference between emulateSdk and reportSdk in Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I know that `Robolectric` is intercepting calls to android classes. However I think I need confirmation of understanding the difference between `emulateSdk` and `reportSdk`.

From java doc I read next:

```
public abstract int emulateSdk
The Android SDK level to emulate.

public abstract int reportSdk
The Android SDK level to report in Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.
```

I interpret this as `emulateSdk` forces `Robolectric` to use classes from specific sdk and emulate behaviour of loading resources or whatever. Where `reportSdk` is actually how sdk level is visible to calling code (basically we mostly use constant to differentiate our code behaviour).

So if I specify `emulateSdk = 14` and `reportSdk = 16` then `Robolectric` will try to behave as 4.0 API but it will be visible as 4.1 to my code or libraries code.

Please confirm if you know the right answer.